# Not getting JQuery response

Tags: jquery

I have the following script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div.msg").hide();
        $("button.show").click(function(){
            $("div.msg").slideDown(2000);
        });
        $("button.hide").click(function(){
            $("div.msg").slideUp(2000);
        });
        $("form.reg").submit(function(){
            var name = $("#name").val();
            if(($("#name").val() == "") || ($("#name").val() == null)){
                $("div.error").html("Name cannot be left blank");
                //alert("Name cannot be left blank");
                return false;
            }
            else{
                $("div.error").html("Name:"+name);
                return true;
            }       
        });
        $("#name").blur(function(){
            var name = $("#name").val();
            alert("Hi! "+name);
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"validate.php",
                data:"name="+name,
                success:function(res){
                    //alert(res);
                    $("#error").val(res);
                }
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

and the validate.php script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    if($name == 'sam')
        echo '<strong>Already taken.</strong>';
    else
        echo '<strong>Avaiable</strong>';
}
else
    echo 'Not Set!';
?>
```

My issue is that I never get the response from this validate page into my div (#error). Please help about how to go about solving the same.

Comment: Do you receive a response from the php script? IE, did your commented alert call have a result?

Comment: try adding an error function to your POST request, and logging the result. Like your success handler, except with `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);}` Maybe that will shed some light on why the POST is failing.

Comment: @Jlange where do I check for the log..??

Comment: You press "F12" in most modern browsers to access the developer tools. Then go to the "Console" tab.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are just using the wrong jQuery function to set the result. From your previous code, it appears that the `#error` selector points a div element, in which case, you'll want to use the function `.html()` to set the response.

Change

```
 $("#error").val(res);
```

to

```
$("#error").html(res);
```

This, of course, is assuming that you got a response in the success function of your POST.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.ajax({                                
    url: "validate.php",
        data: { name: $("#name").val() },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (res) {
        alert(res); 
        //$("#error").val(res);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        }                      
});
```

For these kind of scenarios, tool like firebug will be useful. By navigating to Net-->XHR tab, we get to see the results of the asynchronous requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier if you separate your validation function. Then on your php validation script its safer to use json response.

HTML / Javascript
    
    function form_validation()
    {
        var error = 0;
        var error_msg;

```
    if(($("#name").val() == "") || ($("#name").val() == null)){

        error_msg = "Name cannot be left blank";
        error = 1;
    }else
    {
         $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"validate.php",
                data:"name="+$("#name").val(),
                success:function(res){                    
                    if(res.status=='error')
                    {
                        error_msg = res.msg;
                        error = 1;
                    }
                },
                dataType: "json"
            });
    }

    if(error==1)
    {
        $("div.error").html(error_msg);
        return false;
    }else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    ("#name").blur(function(){
                form_validation();
        }); 

    $("form.reg").submit(function(){

        if(form_validation())
        {
            #### Do ajax post to PHP to save to your DB
        }

        return false; ### Do disable the form submit (page refresh)
    });

  });
</script>
```

PHP validation Script

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    if($name == 'sam')
        $arr = array("status"=>'success','msg'=>'Taken');
    else
        $arr = array("status"=>'success','msg'=>'Available');
}
else
{
    $arr = array("status"=>'error','msg'=>'Error');
}

    echo json_encode($arr);
    exit;
?>
```